# Understanding OpenMP shortcomings regarding fork

Tags: c, openmp

***I wish to understand what do they mean here. Why would this program "hang"?***

From https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/

> OpenMP and `fork()` It is worth mentioning that using OpenMP in a
>   program that calls `fork()` requires special consideration. This
>   problem only affects GCC; ICC is not affected.   If your program
>   intends to become a background process using `daemonize()` or other
>   similar means, you must not use the OpenMP features before the fork.
>   After OpenMP features are utilized, a fork is only allowed if the
>   child process does not use OpenMP features, or it does so as a
>   completely new process (such as after `exec()`).
>
> This is an example of an erroneous program:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>   
> #include <sys/wait.h>   
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> void a(){
>     #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
>     {
>         puts("para_a"); // output twice
>     }
>     puts("a ended"); // output once   
> }
>
> void b(){
>     #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
>     {
>         puts("para_b");
>     }
>     puts("b ended");   
> }
>
> int main(){    
>     a();   // Invokes OpenMP features (parent process)   
>     int p = fork();    
>     if(!p){
>         b(); // ERROR: Uses OpenMP again, but in child process
>         _exit(0);    
>     }    
>     wait(NULL);    
>     return 0;   
> }
> ```
>
> When run, this program hangs, never reaching the line that outputs "b
>   ended". There is currently no workaround as the libgomp API does not
>   specify functions that can be used to prepare for a call to `fork()`.

Comment: Is this execute twice `puts("para_b");`?

Comment: Most probably it has to do with the fact that forking clones just the current thread, while OpenMP expects its thread pool to be there, ready to execute stuff. At the first parallel loop invocation it will start the thread pool and set some flag that it is running, and in `b` it'll just hand off the work to the thread pool - that however isn't backed by any thread, since they aren't present in the new process. In general the "thread" and "fork" models are hard to reconcile, typically you just have to pick one.

Comment: This is a known.  See the `libogmp` bug report:  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52303  Note in the comments:  "POSIX lists just a few functions that you may call after fork before you call _exit or exec*.
#pragma omp parallel is definitely not something you can do after fork from multi-threaded programs."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code as posted violates the POSIX standard.

The [POSIX `fork()` standard states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded
>   process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the
>   calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the
>   states of mutexes and other resources. **Consequently, to avoid
>   errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe
>   operations until such time as one of the `exec` functions is called.**

Running OMP-parallelized code is clearly violating the above restriction.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on Andrew Henle's answer, what `fork(2)` does is create a second process that shares the entire memory space of the calling thread via copy-on-write (CoW) memory mappings. The child process is in an awkward situation - it is a replica of the parent thread with the same state (except the return value of the system call and some other things like timers and resource use counters) and access to all its memory and open file descriptors but without any other thread of execution besides the one that made the `fork(2)` call. While with some precautions this can be used as a crude form of multithreading (and it was used for that purpose before true LWPs were introduced in Unix), 99% of the cases `fork(2)` serves a singular purpose - to spawn child processes whereas the child calls `execve(2)` (or one of its front-ends in the standard C library) immediately after the fork. In recognition of that fact, there is an even more extreme version called `vfork(2)` that doesn't even create CoW mappings of the parent's memory but directly uses its page tables, effectively creating a hybrid between a standalone process and a thread. The child in that case is not even allowed to make async-signal-safe function calls because it operates on the parent's stack.

Note that the OpenMP specification does not cover any interaction with other threading and/or process control mechanisms, thus, even if it might work with some OpenMP implementations, your example is not a correct OpenMP program.

Answer (score 3):

I hit on this in the following scenario:

- Using Python
- Implementing a C++ python extension
- Using OpenMP within this extension
- Using Python multiprocessing parallel execution (which seems to use fork and copy-on-write to provide "free" poor-man-read-only-shared-memory between the sub-processes).
- Invoking the extension within the sub-processes
  => Deadlock.

(Using Python multithreading doesn't work, because the code in each parallel task has significant amount of Python code which then becomes essentially single-threaded due to the GIL. For the same reason, it doesn't make sense to just run the code in serial and only benefit from the parallelization inside the C++ extension.)

Note that invoking parallel functions such as numpy corrcoef somehow does manage to use parallel processing in each of the sub-processes. Presumably it doesn't use OpenMP to do it.

"It would have been nice" in OpenMP had a "reset everything, forget about all previously spawned threads, as if we just started execution". Then we could have invoked this function on the forked child processes and use OpenMP in each one (being careful to reduce the number of used OpenMP threads so as not to overload the system).

Answer (score 2):

This issue was solved in OpenMP 5.0, released at the end of 2018, and widely available in 2019. I'm posting here because my searches initially took me to this page, which provided no solution.

The correct solution for mixing OpenMP and fork is to call

```
omp_pause_resource_all(omp_pause_hard);
```

before calling fork(). This forces OpenMP to place its thread pool in a state which will survive the fork. This call is documented in section 18.6.2 of the OpenMP 5.2 Specification, but the behavior with respect to (Posix-specific) fork is not spelled out there. I found one clear statement this effect in Red Hat's [OpenMP 5.0 announcement](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/19/whats-new-in-openmp-5-0).

I have confirmed that this solution works (and is required) with the LLVM-based oneAPI Intel compilers.

Answer (score -1):

It is clearly a dead lock scenario. And it is happening exactly in below code. As it internally implementing thread/fork() again to execute `puts("para_b");` in parallel. It some how trapped in a dead lock.

```
 #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
 {
   puts("para_b");//in a trap means dead lock
 }
```

Comment: *Use a mutex and try.*  Don't guess.

Comment: It is not clear how `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)` replace `puts("para_b");` this line during compilation. Hence suggesting to use a mutex. Yes mutex is not going to solve the issue. So modified my answer. Thanks

Comment: It is actually quite clear. Just run GCC with the `-fdump-tree-all` argument and examine the output of the OpenMP lowering step. The body of the parallel region is outlined in a separate function, which is then either called directly by the master thread or indirectly by GOMP in the worker threads. No changes whatsoever are done to the content of the block.

Comment: The blocking occurs in the GOMP code as it is waiting for the OpenMP worker threads to awake and pick up the work items, but those threads are simply not there as `fork(2)` only forks the calling thread. The execution either never enters the body of the parallel region or hangs at the implicit barrier at its end.